# Powershell - substitute inside Here-String

Tags: powershell

I need to use `if` statement inside `here-string`. But when I look inside variable then I see `true` instead of `$true`
expression `$($row.'Secondary Network Adapter' -eq 'Y')` will be substituted by `$true` or `$false`.

```
$row = @{
    SecondaryNetworkAdapter = "Y"
}

$code1 = @'
    if($($row.SecondaryNetworkAdapter -eq 'Y')){
        Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias '$nic1Name' -AutomaticMetric disabled -InterfaceMetric 5
    }
'@
```

then, I am running the following line:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($code1)
```

Output:

> ```
> if(True){
>   Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias 'LAN' -AutomaticMetric disabled -InterfaceMetric 5
> }
> ```

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2):

Add an escaped literal `$` before the expression:

```
if(`$$($row.SecondaryNetworkAdapter -eq 'Y')){
```